# How to GET data From Ajax Jquery serializeArray() in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have try to Process Form array with jquery ajax json to php.

my code **tesJSONarray.php**

```
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

      $('.SAVE').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault(); 

        var str = JSON.stringify($("#COBA").serializeArray());

         alert(str);


           $.ajax({

              type:"POST",
              dataType:"json",
              url:"tesJSONarray2.php",
              data:str,
              success: function(data) {
                   $("#data").html(data);


               },

           });      

      });

  });


</script>

<!--div id='data'></data-->

<form id='COBA' method="post">
  <input type='text' name='NAME[]' class='NAME' value="septiyo"><br>
  <input type='text' name='NAME[]' class='NAME' value="naf'an"><br>
  <input type='submit' value='SAVE' name='SAVE' class='SAVE'>
</form>
```

And my action file **tesJSONarray2.php**

```
$name = $_POST['NAME'];
foreach ($name as $x) {
    echo json_encode($x);
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
```

but it not work. How Can I process the variable on PHP.?

Usually if I use **serialize()** I know value from PHP with

```
echo json_encode($variable);
```

but with serializeArray() not working.

anyone can help me?

thanks in advance.

Comment: tried `echo json_encode($name);`? btw: `header` should be before any output.

Comment: I hve tried your advice but stil not work. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change data :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    data:{'str':str}
</script>

<?php
   print_r($_POST) // in json 
   print_r(json_decode($_POST['str'],true)) //for array
?>
```

Comment: You should not access the superglobal $_POST array directly, use a filter function instead e.g. `$str = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'str');`

Comment: @Paramjeet I have try it but still now Show My variabel?

Comment: @Uchsun it can't show 'NAME' it is undefined because you are using ajax post that's why you only access jquery ajax datastring not your form data

Comment: @Paramjeet so how can I access that 'NAME' variable? can i Acces it with forceach or something?